# Connected $T_2$ space with essentially no connected subspaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is there a connected $T_2$ space $(X,\tau)$ with more than one point, such that the singletons and $X$ are the only connected subspaces of $X$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such space.  For if $x$ is any point and $X\setminus \{x\}=U|V$ then $\{x\}\cup U$ and $\{x\}\cup V$ are connected sets, each with more than one point and different from $X$.

The closest thing you can get is a connected set whose connected subsets are cofinite.  The axiom CH implies there is a countable connected Hausdorff space with this property [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1994-122-03/S0002-9939-1994-1287102-2/S0002-9939-1994-1287102-2.pdf) that is not too complicated (relative to the completely regular example).  I don't think a Hausdorff example has ever been constructed in ZFC.

Comment: What is $X\setminus \{x\}=U|V$?

Comment: Assuming $X\setminus \{x\}$ is not connected (otherwise the space fails to have the desired property), it is equal to the union of two disjoint nonempty open sets $U$ and $V$.

Comment: I've never seen this notation -- but I like it.

Comment: Why are the sets $\{x\}\cup U$ and $\{x\}\cup V$ connected?

Comment: A standard notation for disjoint unions is $U\sqcup V$ ($\backslash$sqcup)

Comment: @erz If $U\cup\{x\}$ is not connected, write it as $W\sqcup Y$ with $x\in Y$, $W,Y$ both nonempty and closed in $U\cup\{x\}$. Then $X=W\sqcup (Y\cup V)$ and both are closed and nonempty.

Comment: Incidentally, this shows that every infinite connected Hausdorff space admits an infinite connected proper subset which is either open (as the complement of a singleton) or closed. Iterating, we obtain a strictly decreasing sequence of connected subsets, each of which has finite complement in its closure.

Comment: The answer actually shows that $T_1$ axiom is enough. No need to assume $T_2$.